# Laravel 5.6: Multiple primary key defined error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations, mysql-error-1068

I created this migration script, but it gives the following error. It wont give any error if I changed the data type of the another column to string or something else. How to solve this issue?

```
    Schema::create('incidents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id');
        $table->primary('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id', 255);
    });
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined (SQL: alter table `incidents` add primary key `incidents_id_primary`(`id`))

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined

**Edit**

Because nothing is working I moved this user_id creation to another migration script. Now it still fails to run the second migration script. Gives this error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined (SQL:  alter table `incidents` add `user_id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key)

It seems, if the primary key is not integer, then Laravel tries to make next first integer column primary!!!

So my first script is,

```
 public function up()
 {
     Schema::create('incidents', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->string('id')->primary();
     });
 }
```

Second script is,

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::table('incidents', function($table) {
     $table->unsignedInteger('user_id', 255);
   });
}
```

Comment: you can't have 2 columns with the same name 
`$table->string('id');
        $table->primary('id');` change it to something like `$table->string('string_id');
        $table->primary('id');`

Comment: $table->string('id');
        $table->primary('id'); use only  one

Comment: Yes I replaced it with  $table->string('id')->primary(); too. But no any difference, same error. And the above syntax in the question works well if I change unsigned integer to string.!!!

Comment: why do you want id as a string and not just use an integer  as primary?

Comment: Could you post the others migrations of this table as well? - @SameeraK

Comment: @mrQubeMaster: My primary key is a uuid, that's why its a string.

Comment: @AlbertoGuilherme: I updated

Comment: @SameeraK - Did you try to remove the second parameter  on `$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Make it like this:

```
Schema::create('incidents', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->string('id')->primary();
     $table->unsignedInteger('another_column');
});
```

And dont forget to add on your model

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
public $incrementing = false; //If you dont want the auto-increment
```

**Problem**

Acording to [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html)

```
unsignedInteger(string $column, bool $autoIncrement = false)
```

The function you use receives a bool as parameter and the number 255 was being interpreted as true. I think the DB makes the autoIncrement a `primary_key`

Comment: @SameeraK try it like this

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Only issue was that number in parentheses. Its so strange error.

Comment: @SameeraK I added an explanation, i hope it can lighten your day =)